# How to disable the next and the next month and how to disable certain days (grayed out)?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-4

How to disable the next and the next month and how to disable certain days (grayed out) ?
fullcalendar v4

Comment: Please visit help center, take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for related topics on Stackoverflow; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also fullcalendar-4 is a tag. I added it

Comment: You should also post your code as a [mcve]. It looks like you're having some problem with your existing code.

Comment: [Please do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=fullcalendar+4+disable+days+site%3Astackoverflow.com)